# Do I need to winterize black polyethylene sprinkler pipe?

Tags: sprinkler-system, irrigation, freezing

A gentleman at the sprinkler supply store told me black polyethylene sprinkler pipe doesn't need to be protected from freezing; that it can handle the expansion.  I'm looking for a second opinion on this.

Should I add drains and/or blow out the system in the fall?  Can it really be ignored over winter?

Note: Local building code assumes a 30" frost depth.  My line is 12" below surface.

Comment: The pipe probably can, but can the rest of the system.  Would drain/blow out water from whole system to be safe.  Expansion of pipe will probably weaken it over time.  Used that pipe in a barn, pipes did okay, but other parts would burst if water froze.

Comment: I try not to be _too_ cynical, but remember that the guy at the sprinkler supply store is hoping you'll come back to purchase repair parts to replace anything that fails...

Answer (score 1):

I live in Oregon and can tell you that you are taking a chance even here with the depth you are talking about if you don’t drain the system or blow them out you may make it 5 or even 10 years but a hard freeze can not only damage the pipe but also split the sprinklers.

Even a moderate climate can get cold enough to really destroy a system that would last for many years if the water was turned off and drained or compressed air used to blow some of the water out.

But my installer said it would be ok! All he has to do is say it was much colder than normal and this was not expected.

Just saying if it never gets below 27 ok you can take a chance I have seen too many damaged in this area and some winters don’t get cold enough many do.

Answer (score 0):

I live in Northern Utah, where we have hard freezes every winter. I've never blown out my black poly pipe, but I do at least drain the system: a half-full pipe freezes differently than one completely full of water.

Sprinkler bodies, PVC couplers, and valves are a different story.

Comment: Thanks @spuck.  How do you drain the system?  Manual valves?

Comment: Half of my system is on enough of a slope that opening a couple of hose spigots lets air in at the top and water at the bottom. Then I remove the solenoids from my valves and leave it at that.